# How to access extensionContext in a UIHostingController subclass?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I'm fairly new to extensions in iOS and would like to use SwiftUI for the extension

so I've subclassed UIHostingController and then I've tried to access the extensionContext as I was previously in a UIViewController I had previously set as the class in the storbyboard.

I thought this was a complete implemention of UIViewController? It appears extensionContext is only populated when you use a UIViewController as the root?

How can I go about rendering SwiftUI view and pass the provided items down?

```
class ShareViewController: UIViewController {
//    @IBOutlet var container: UIView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        guard let extensionItems = extensionContext?.inputItems as? [NSExtensionItem] else {
            return
        }
        // in the debugger I get here and theres 1 item in the extensionItems
        for extensionItem in extensionItems {
            if let itemProviders = extensionItem.attachments {
```

```
class MainSwiftUIView: UIHostingController<MainUIView> {
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder, rootView: MainUIView(urlShared: ""))
    }
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        guard let extensionItems = self.extensionContext?.inputItems as? [NSExtensionItem] else {
            return // debugger exits here... :(
        }
        // the debugger doesn't reach here 
        for extensionItem in extensionItems {
```

Comment: Possibly related: [Accessing extensionContext from a presented view controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25544918/accessing-extensioncontext-from-a-presented-view-controller)